Use Lambda to send alert to SNS Topic - but only send email once per unique body
I have an IoT workflow with various devices sending data to an S3 bucket, which triggers a Lambda. The Lambda processes the data and may trigger an alert (e.g. due to DeviceX having a temperature above Y). I wish to receive email alerts when a new device encounters such an alert with a maximum of receiving one email per device per day.
The solution I am hoping to implement is to setup the SNS writer to output an email body for the SNS Topic endpoint which includes the device ID (which is globally unique across my devices), the alert ID and the date.
In the SNS setup I want to make it so that my subscribers receive an email when the first such event happens. But since the Lambda may be triggered several times per hour by the same device ID, they should not receive a new email for every such invocation, even if the alert condition is still true. If another device encounters an alert, that should still trigger a new separate email - and similarly, if the first device continues to be in the alert state the next day, a new email will be sent because now the date changes.
I believe this may be linked to subscription filters or deduplication, but I have not been able to find the right solution for this.

The SNS message filtering feature is not helpful for this use case. The SNS deduplication feature only works within a 5 minute time window. You can't count on SNS to handle this for you if you care about a 24 hour time period. You need to have code in your Lambda function that determines if it actually needs to send the message to SNS or if the same message has already been sent recently.
The best way to handle this is to create a DynamoDB table that your Lambda function stores your message in before it sends them. Before sending a message, it would check if that message already exists in the DynamoDB table, if so, it would skip sending the message to SNS.
You would configure TTL expiration on the DynamoDB messages, so that they are automatically deleted from the table after 24 hours.

One thing to be aware of, the record in DynamoDB may not actually be deleted until some time after the TTL value expires. So for the solution to be more precise, your Lambda function would need to check if the message already exists in the database, and if it does exist, compare the record's TTL value against the current time before deciding if it should skip sending the message again.

Thank you for the suggestion. I was hoping there would be an equivalent functionality to the 5 min deduplication, but for longer intervals. Adding dynamoDB for this would be a lot of complexity and I was hoping there would be a simpler workaround inspired by the de duplication logic - but maybe there is not

The deduplicate logic for both SQS and SNS is just to prevent a duplicate message from happening over a few minutes time frame. These messaging services do not retain anything about the message content for any longer time period than that. You have to build this sort of thing yourself using a database.

I think we will take an approach similar to this, but use S3 Parquet files to store the information of whether an alert has been triggered or not, i.e. playing the same rolas the DynamoDB in the outlined answer.

With that approach, Lambda would have to download the entire parquet file, query it, update it if necessary, and then push the entire new file back to S3, which is very inefficient. Also, if you have more than one instance of the Lambda function running at the same time you will run into concurrency issues with that approach.

The idea would be that a single Parquet file would be written per device-day combination. For example, in my data lake I would have s3bucket/aggregations/alerts/<alert_id>_<date>_<device_id>.parquet. The Lambda will thus be able to GET a specific object based on info known during run-time. If it succeeds, the Lambda will know that the alert has already triggered an SNS message for this particular alertid/deviceid/date combination and will avoid sending a new message. If it fails, the Lambda creates the file. Each Parquet would be 1 row of meta information, I would not try to append data.

OK, so you are basically using S3 as a database. That should work I guess. It doesn't seem like you even need parquet files at this point, it could just be an empty text file or something, since the existence of the file is all you care about here.  I don't understand the aversion to DynamoDB, as I think it would certainly be no more complicated than your S3 solution, but I understand going with what you are comfortable with.

You are completely correct, my initial thread lacks context: Our setup involves the IoT device uploading data to an S3 'input bucket', triggering the Lambda which outputs decoded data to an S3 'output bucket'. Because of this, we are already using S3 as our 'data lake', which makes it more seamless than using DynamoDB. The motivation for storing Parquet files (rather than empty files, e.g.) would purely be that we can then visualize those Parquet files as well in Grafana via the Athena data source, which is already used in this work flow.
